# Is there a list of 'use client' React features?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am updating to next 13 and want to take advantage of React Server components.  Reading the [use client](https://react.dev/reference/react/use-client) documentation it specifies that `use client` is needed for client-only React features.

Is there a list of what all these features are? So far I am only seeing `context`, `useState`, and `useEffect`.  Are there other features I should worry about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do some extensive testing with this and as of 2023 here are my findings.

### **NOT** allowed in server components:

| Built-in React APIs | Hooks |
| --- | --- |
| Component | useState |
| createContext | useContext |
| createFactory | useRef |
| createRef | useEffect |
| PureComponent | useTransition |
|  | useDeferredValue |
|  | useSyncExternalStore |
|  | useImperativeHandle |
|  | useInsertionEffect |
|  | useLayoutEffect |
|  | useOptimistic |
|  | useReducer |

### **ARE** allowed in server components:

| Built-in React APIs | Hooks |
| --- | --- |
| forwardRef | useMemo |
| lazy | useCallback |
| memo | use |
| startTransition | useDebugValue |
| Children | useId |
| cloneElement |  |
| createElement |  |
| isValidElement |  |

Answer (score 1):

things that you counted are hooks. hooks are functions that hooked into the component lifecycle so you can prepare the display UI accordingly. in general, you use `use client` when you need to use the browser features:

- browser-only API, such as the window, localStorage, or document objects.
- event listeners such as `onClick`, `onChange`. interactive UI is available only on the browser
- real time chat, maybe you have a chat app.
- real time data. maybe you  have a component that displays a real-time stock ticker. it needs to be updated in response to changes in the stock market. These changes happen in real-time, so the component needs to be able to update itself without having to wait for the server to respond.